# What is the process after the Add Token delegate is called in a Stripe iOS implementation?

Tags: ios, swift, stripe-payments

I'm using Stripe and iOS to add payments to my application.

I know I need to submit the token and other information to my server to complete the process, but I'm not sure what to do with the function to show success, dismiss the Stripe controller, and return to my app.

```
func addCardViewController(_ addCardViewController: STPAddCardViewController, didCreateToken token: STPToken, completion: @escaping STPErrorBlock) {
    self.submitTokenToBackend(token: token, completion: { (error: Error?) in
        if let error = error {
            completion(error)
        } else {
            self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: {
                //self.showReceiptPage()
                completion(nil)
            })
        }
    })
}

func submitTokenToBackend(token: STPToken, completion: (_ error:Error)->()){
    print("doing this")
}
```

I'm using Alamofire as my transport engine.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using Stripe too with swift and asp.net web api on server, I'll put the complete proccess I use that is working perfectly:

1) Server - asp.net web api with library stripe:

```
    [Route("PostCharge")]
    [HttpPost]
    [ResponseType(typeof(Ride))]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> PostCharge(StripeChargeModel model)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }
        var chargeId = await ProcessPayment(model);
        return Ok(chargeId);
    }

    private async Task<string> ProcessPayment(StripeChargeModel model)
    {
        return await Task.Run(() =>
        {
            var myCharge = new StripeChargeCreateOptions
            {
                Amount = (int)(model.Amount * 100),
                Currency = "usd",
                Description = model.CardHolderName + "Charge",
                StatementDescriptor = model.CardHolderName,
                SourceTokenOrExistingSourceId = model.Token
            };
            var chargeService = new StripeChargeService("sk_test_laskdjfasdfafasd");
            var stripeCharge = chargeService.Create(myCharge);
            return stripeCharge.Id;
        });
    }
```

2) Swift 3 with Alamofire and Stripe library:

```
        STPAPIClient.shared().createToken(withCard: card, completion: { (token, error) -> Void in
        if error != nil {
            self.hideProgress()
            self.showAlert(self, message: "Internet is not working")
            print(error)
            return
        }
        let params : [String : AnyObject] = ["Token": token!.tokenId as AnyObject, "Amount": paymentAmount as AnyObject, "CardHolderName": AppVars.RiderName as AnyObject]

        Alamofire.request(url + "/api/postcharge", method: .post, parameters: params, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: [ "Authorization": "Bearer " + token]).responseJSON { response in
            switch response.result {
            case .failure(_):
                self.hideProgress()
                self.showAlert(self, message: "Internet is not working")
            case .success(_):
                let dataString:NSString = NSString(data: response.data!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)!
                if (dataString as? String) != nil {
                   self.showAlert(self, message: "Your payment has been successful")
                } else {
                  self.showAlert(self, message: "Your payment has not been successful. Please, try again")
                }
            }
        }
    })
```

3) swift 3, insert a line in application of AppDelegate:

```
   func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    STPPaymentConfiguration.shared().publishableKey = "pk_test_xxasdfasdfasdf"
    return true
}
```

Comment: thanks I will look over this this evening....and see what I can make out of it. I noticed that you are calling the create token and server call all together.

Comment: Ok...any doubt about I'm here and if this helps you...take your vote...

Comment: Am having doubt in STRIPE. Am trying to addCardViewController (STPAddCardViewController()) , after entered my CardDetails, I clicked ADD button, nothing happened. I have used same code as "BOSTON" used, kindly help me on this.

Comment: @McDonal_11 My way is working fine, I don't use like Boston posted.